# Setting environment variables when running docker in detached mode

Tags: bash, shell, docker

If I include the following line in /root/.bashrc:

```
export $A = "AAA"
```

then when I run the docker container in interactive mode (docker run -i), the $A variable keeps its value. However if I run the container in detached mode I cannot access the variable. Even if I run the container explicitly sourcing the .bashrc like

```
docker run -d my_image /bin/bash -c "cd /root && source .bashrc && echo $A"
```

such line produces an empty output.

So, why is this happening? And how can I set the environment variables defined in the .bashrc file?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that the command you are running has `$A` being interpreted by your hosts shell (not the container shell). On your host, `$A` is likely black, so your effectively command becomes:

```
docker run -i my_image /bin/bash -c "cd /root && source .bashrc && echo "
```

Which does exactly as it says. We can escape the variable so it is sent to the container and properly evaluated there:

```
docker run -i my_image /bin/bash -c "echo \$A"
```

But this will also be blank because, although the container is, the shell is not in interactive mode. But we can force it to be:

```
docker run -i my_image /bin/bash -i -c "echo \$A"
```

Woohoo, we finally got our desired result. But with an added error from bash because there is no TTY. So, instead of interactive mode, we can just set a psuedo-TTY:

```
docker run -t my_image /bin/bash -i -c "echo \$A"
```

Comment: Awesome! Just one issue, the last two code snippets are the same. What is the code for setting the pseudo-TTY? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I modified it to be `-t` (pseudo TTY) instead of `-i`. But it could also be `-it` (pseudo TTY and interactive). The point I was trying to illustrate was that the interactive console wasn't inherited by bash itself and still has to be set on bash.

Comment: Sorry but the question title explicitly asked about "detached mode" and your answer does the opposite. anyone has found a way in detached mode?

Answer (score 1):

After running some tests, it appears that when running a container in detached mode, overidding the default environment variables doesnt always happen the way we want, depending on where you are in the Dockerfile.

As an exemple if, running a container in a detached container like so:

```
docker run **-d** --name image_name_container image_name
```

Whatever ENV variables you defined **within** the Dockerfile takes effect everywhere (read the rest and you will understand what the *everywhere* means).

example of a simple dockerfile (alpine is just a lighweight linux distribution):

```
FROM alpine:latest

#declaring a docker env variable and giving it a default value
ENV MY_ENV_VARIABLE dummy_value

#copying two dummy scripts into a place where i can execute them straight away
COPY ./start.sh /usr/sbin
COPY ./not_start.sh /usr/sbin

#in this script i could do: echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE > /test1.txt
RUN not_start.sh
RUN echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE > /test2.txt

#in this script i could do: echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE > /test3.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["start.sh"]
```

Now if you want to run your container in **detached** and override some ENV variables, like so:

```
docker run **-d** -e MY_ENV_VARIABLE=new_value --name image_name_container image_name
```

Surprise! The var MY_ENV_VARIABLE is only overidden inside the script that is run in the ENTRYPOINT (and i checked, same thing happens if your replace `ENTRYPOINT` with `CMD`). It would also be overidden in a subscript that you could call from this *start.sh* script. But the MY_EV_VARIABLE variables that are called within a `RUN` dockerfile command or within the dockerfile itself do not get overidden.

In other words we would have ***$MY_ENV_VARIABLE*** being replaced by the value ***dummy_value*** and ***new_value*** depending on if you are in the `ENTRYPOINT` or not.

Comment: I did not see any mention of this in the Docker official documdentation.
[https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement]

Hence i left this message for everyone's sake.